# How does Sage order its symmetric group elements?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, sagemath

In Sage, the symmetric group is a list. For instance if $G$ = SymmetricGroup($3$), we have

\begin{align*}
G[0] & = e  \\
G[1] & = (1,3,2)\\
G[2] & = (1,2,3) \\
G[3] &= (2,3)\\
G[4] &= (1,3) \\
G[5] & = (1,2)
\end{align*}

I am simply wondering what is the ordering that Sage is using. I am fairly certain it's not "random".

Comment: Cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442835)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sage doesn’t have specific code to iterate over the symmetric group $S_n$; it treats $S_n$ like any other permutation group and uses a general algorithm to generate all elements of a permutation group from its generators.

I’ll be linking to lines from the following source files below:

Sage code that constructs $S_n$ as a permutation group: [sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_named](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_named.py)

Sage code that generates the elements of permutation groups [sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.py)

GAP code that constructs a stabilizer chain for permutation groups: [stbc.gi](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/master/lib/stbc.gi) and [stbc.gd](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/master/lib/stbc.gd)

The $n$-cycle $(1\ldots n)$ and the transposition $(12)$ are used as generators of $S_n$ ([here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/f449b14ecae7a704739467245cf5e7561dfec490/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_named.py#L271-L274)). Sage calls GAP to compute a stabilizer chain and a corresponding strong generating set for the permutation group. These concepts are explained in the GAP manual section [Stabilizer Chains](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EGAP/WWW2/Gap3/Manual3/C021S006.htm) and the Wikipedia article on [strong generating sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_generating_set). The code that does this (starting [here](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/577dcecf9bff8ba8357546983785d77d658b76f3/lib/stbc.gi#L62)) is rather involved, and I don’t know how it works, but for $n\ge5$ the “strong generating system” that is computed ([here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/f449b14ecae7a704739467245cf5e7561dfec490/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.py#L2029-L2034)) from the results has a regular structure. Each element $L_k$, with $1\le k\le n$, is a list of $k$ permutations $\sigma_{kl}$, with $1\le l\le k$, each of which is a cycle or a power of a cycle, as follows:

$$
\sigma_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
(n-k+l,\dotsc,n-k+1)&k\lt n-1\;,\\
(n,\dotsc,2)^{l-1}&k=n-1\;,\\
(n,\dotsc,1)^{l-1}&k=n,l\lt3\;,\\
(n,\dotsc,1)^{l-2}&k=n,l\gt3\;,\\
(12)&k=n,l=3\;.\\
\end{cases}
$$

For instance, for $n=5$, this is

\begin{eqnarray}
L_1&=&(())\;,\\
L_2&=&((),(54))\;,\\
L_3&=&((),(43),(543))\;,\\
L_4&=&((),(5432),(53)(42),(5234)\;,\\
L_5&=&((),(54321),(12),(53142),(52413))\;.
\end{eqnarray}

This is obviously rather arbitrary and dependent on implementation details, as Sean Eberhard emphasizes in [an answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442835).

The group elements are then produced ([here](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/f449b14ecae7a704739467245cf5e7561dfec490/src/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.py#L1212-L1222)) as products $L_{1,l_1}\circ\dotsb\circ L_{n,l_n}$ of $n$ factors, one from each list, one group element for each of the $n!$ tuples $(l_1,\dotsc,l_n)$ in lexical order. Thus, for instance for $n=5$ the first few elements are

$$
(),(54321),(12),(53142),(52413),(5432),(5432)\circ(54321)=(153)(24),(5432)\circ(12)=(12543).
$$

The strong generating systems for $n\lt5$ are different. For $n=2$

\begin{eqnarray}
L_1&=&(())\;,\\
L_2&=&((),(21))\;,\\
\end{eqnarray}

for $n=3$

\begin{eqnarray}
L_1&=&(())\;,\\
L_2&=&((),(32))\;,\\
L_3&=&((),(321),(312))\;,\\
\end{eqnarray}

and for $n=4$

\begin{eqnarray}
L_1&=&(())\;,\\
L_2&=&((),(43))\;,\\
L_3&=&((),(234),(243))\;,\\
L_4&=&((),(13)(24),(14)(23),(12)(34))\;.
\end{eqnarray}